# Need help to understand this specific double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The paper I am reading says:

$$ \mathcal{L}^2 f[X(t_0)] \int_{t_0}^{t} \int_{t_0}^{\tau_1} d\tau_2 d\tau_1 = \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{L}^2f[X(t_0)] (t - t_0)^2 $$

I do not understand how the double integral $\int_{t_0}^{t} \int_{t_0}^{\tau_1} d\tau_2 d\tau_1$ results in $\frac{1}{2}(t - t_0)^2$.

Can someone please explain?

Many thanks

Comment: What would $\int_{t_0}^t dt $ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{t_0}^{\tau_1}d\tau_2=\int_{t_0}^{\tau_1}1\cdot d\tau_2=\tau_2|_{t_0}^{\tau_1}=\tau_1-t_0$$
Next, $$\int_{t_0}^t(\tau_1-t_0)d\tau_1=\left(\frac{1}{2}\tau_1^2-t_0\tau_1\right)|_{t_0}^t=\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-t_0t\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}t_0^2-t_0^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}t^2-t_0t+\frac{1}{2}t_0^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(t^2-2t_0t+t_0^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-t_0\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason I got confused by the two variables of integration being time quantity... Everything is clear now!